# Какие алгоритмы и паттерны должен знать каждый junior Python разработчик?

Tags: python, алгоритм, шаблоны-проектирования

посоветуйте какие алгоритмы и паттерны должен знать каждый Junior Python разработчик? Я только сортировку пузырьком знаю, ну и рекурсию, если это алгоритм, а среди паттернов проектирования понятие не имею , что приоритетно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не существует какого-то списка алгоритмов и паттернов, обязательных для того или иного профессионального уровня.

Работать программистом **начального** уровня вполне можно и без их знания. Хотя знать всё-таки лучше, чем не знать. Но в целом их изучение нужно больше для того, чтобы развивать "мышление программиста", а не для того, чтобы прямо использовать их в повседневной практике. (Я сейчас не говорю про какие-то очень специальные ниши, где алгоритмы всё-таки непосредственно используются).

Я бы порекомендовал на данном этапе сконцентрироваться не на алгоритмах и паттернах, а на том, чтобы наработать практику в написании хотя бы не очень больших, но уже настоящих программ, которые решают настоящие задачи - какие-нибудь телеграмм-боты, веб-парсеры и т.п.

Изучение паттернов гораздо проще происходит, когда у вас уже наработан опыт написания кода, который по размеру побольше, чем просто сортировка.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!